# How to view selected items in full list of ion-select component?

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-ngmodel, ionic4, ion-select

I have a list of cards and get json from server in such structere:

```
object1 : {
  prop1 : ''
  listOfObjects : []
}
```

so object1 has many to many relationship with object in listOfObjects. 
And i get only objects that linked with relationship with my main object of view.

To view this linked objects i use ion-select component of ionic 4. 
And i need to tick as selected only linked object from all objects. for eg.

```
Full list of objects
obj1
obj2
obj3
obj4
```

Objects that linked to main model

- obj1
- obj2

And in ion-select it will be like that

- obj1 [selected]
- obj2 [selected]
- obj3
- obj4

How i can get it???

projectService.projectsList>> get all project from server
sprintService.selectedSprint.projects >> linked projects to sprint

Please give me any alternative for this issue if it is imposible with ion-select... Thanks all.

```js
<ion-select #projects ngModel name="projects" [(ngModel)]="sprintService.selectedSprint.projects"
                    multiple="true">
                    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let project of projectService.projectsList" [value]="project">
                      {{project.name}}
                    </ion-select-option>
                  </ion-select> 

my model
export class Sprint{
    id : number;
    name : string;
    description : string;
    startDate : string;
    endDate : string;
    priority : number;
    projects : Project[]
}

export class Project{
    id : number;
    name : string;
    description : string;
    startDate : string;
    endDate : string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a compare function, and that way be sure what projects are selected. Something like this.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="projects" multiple="true" [compareWith]="compareObject">
   <ion-select-option *ngFor="let p of sprintService.selectedSprint.projects" [value]="p">{{p.name}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

compareObject(a: any, b: any) {
   return a.id === b.id;
}
```

Comment: I have already tryed this method but i had an error like this:
Can't bind to 'compareWith' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select'.
1. If 'ion-select' is an Angular component and it has 'compareWith' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-select' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ..... bla bla
I saw this issue but don`t know how to fix it :( [issue about this error](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14598)

Comment: Sounds like you are on an older version of Ionic 4. compareWith was added in version 4.1.0. Ref. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.1.0

Comment: Yes! It works after 
npm i @ionic/angular >> and updated to 4.1.2 ver. of Ionic Framework. 
Thank you Remi!!!!